# OS-X: check if process runs from bundle or not

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'd like to check if a given remote process executable is part of a bundle or just a stand alone executable. My method is a very straight forward one that deeply rely on the assumption that if the executable is found inside /[exec_name].app/ subtree, this must be its containing bundle (see below)

I wish to find relevant cocoa framework for that, that cover all possible cases,.

```
char path[MAXPATHLEN+1] = {0};
int ret = proc_pidinfo(pid, PROC_PIDPATHINFO, 0,&path, sizeof(path));
if (!ret) {
    std::string app_suffix(".app");
    unsigned long split_idx = path.rfind(app_suffix);
    if (split_idx != std::string::npos)
        cout << "found bundle : " << path.substr(0,split_idx+app_suffix.size());
    else 
       cout << " stand alone executable \n"; 
}
```

I also found another way to get the bundle out of executable name using applescript, but I prefer to find the equivalent in cocoa or core-foundation.

get bundle identifier (apple script):

```
osascript -e 'on run args
set output to {}
repeat with a in args
set end of output to id of app a
end
set text item delimiters to linefeed
output as text
end' Finder '[name of executable]’
```

from bundle identifier, it's easy to access bundle itself (in cocoa):

```
NSBundle* myBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"<bundle_identifier>"]
```

thanks for the help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you just want [NSRunningApplication](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/index.html).

The class includes `bundleIdentifier` & `bundleURL` properties.

Answer (score -1):

add something along those lines:

```
if "your process here" using "api.bundle or whatever bundle you want to check"
```

this only checks for one process though

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. perhaps you can write the exact code, so i can have better understanding of you method. thanks again